# Converting NSString of Ti86 style format into double, or NSString that contains a double or error

Tags: ios, nsstring, calculator

I've built my own, but I'm rebuilding my calculator for the up coming changes. I'm sure their is a much better way go about it.

I want to pass an NSString string with Ti format to something, and have it return an NSString or a double. With out the pesky 4.000000000000000001 showing up some times, (that and I never figured out how to implement the negative symbol).

I'm sure some one has done it better than I, (it may even be in the documentation), but I can't seem to find it. Does anyone have a link, to something better than what I have working.

Comment: What is the "Ti86 format"? Can you show some sample input and the expected result? What exactly is the problem with the negative symbol?

Comment: Ti86 format, is the format for the calculator I've been using for the last 15+ years. It accepts an infixed notated expression, and returns the result, or syntax error. 

The problem with negative numbers is I never figured out how to get the negative buttons input through the shunting yard, without error.

Comment: 5(SIN 30) 

should equal 2.5

etc

Comment: Many people reading the iOS questions (including me) might not be familiar with that format, so a link to the documentation plus some samples might be helpful.

Comment: So you want to *evaluate* the expression? - If you already have a (partial) implementation then you could show that.

Comment: Yes Martin, I want to evalutate the expression. The CalculatorClass I built for this task is to large to post. I would like a simple method call that is more proven.

Comment: Perhaps have a look as https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser. I haven't used it, but it is often referenced as a solution for parsing and evaluating mathematical expressions. It knows about implicit multiplication, but function arguments always require parentheses, so `SIN 30` might not work.